# Building web services and updating client application with MSBuild

Tags: c#, web-services, msbuild

I have a solution that contains two projects (web services and client application).

When i built solution, i always need to update Web References manually (web service's proxies).

Is there any way to do it automatically with MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [svcutil.exe](http://www.svcutil.com/) to create the proxy for you. You just have to get all the parameters right.

Answer (score 0):

You could share contracts via a Contracts DLL if that makes sense for you from a design perspective (you'll be breaking loose coupling) and you have the tooling (the WCF wizards make it easier to do)